# how can i set the jdk in intellij 9 on mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, java

I have a project on intellij and now i wanna run it on intellinj 9 on mac. when i run the project i get the error -> "the JDK is not specifiedfor module "XXXXX" specify the JDK in Configuration project". when i go there in the dependencie for module SDk there is No Project JDk. and when i click on new it is just JSDK, Intellij idea plugin SDK,Flex SDK,AIR SDK, Flexmojos SDk and Mobile SDK

What can I do?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-sdks.html). You need to add new JSDK with the following path:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
```

Comment: Thanks man this helped me in Intellij Idea 12.1.3 with Java 7 x64.

Comment: Same here, intelliJ 14.1.3, Yosemite

Answer (score 5):

Agreed. Going one step further, I would recommend setting up the different sdk's explicitly for Java 5, 6, etc.

On OS 10.6, use:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Home
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home
```