# Gradle IDEA Plugin can't find JDK on Mac

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, gradle, sdkman

**PLEASE NOTE: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE.** I want **Gradle's IDEA plugin** to correctly configure my IntelliJ IDEA CE project for me. I am not interested in any solution that involves *manually* tuning IntelliJ to find my JDK. This is a Gradle IDEA plugin feature that can and should work.

If you can find another question that involves correctly getting the Gradle IDEA plugin to configure IntelliJ (running on a Mac) so that it can find JDK 8+, then please by all means, mark this as a dupe and provide a link to that question. **Otherwise, do not vote this as a dupe (it's not!).**

---

Mac 10.9.5 here. Java 8 is my default JRE/JDK, and I just installed Groovy 2.4.6 and Gradle 2.13 via [`sdkman`](http://sdkman.io). I then installed [IntelliJ IDEA CE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/).

On my terminal, I created a `test-proj` directory, and then inside that directory I issued the following Gradle command:

```
gradle init --type groovy-library
```

Gradle executed successfully, giving me a Groovy project skeleton. I then edited the generated `build.gradle` to contain the IDEA plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

And then I ran:

```
gradle wrapper
./gradlew clean idea
```

This generated the Gradle Wrapper for me, and I then used the IDEA plugin to generate IntelliJ project files for me. I then opened my brand-spanking-new IntelliJ IDE and went to `Open` my `test-proj`.

The project opened and everything *appeared* to be OK. But then I started coding and noticed that JRE classes such as `String` were not showing up as resolvable. So I went to `File >> Project Structure` and see this:

[image]

So it appears that IntelliJ can't find my default Java 8 JDK. I *know* the OS can find **both** the JRE and the JDK, based on the console ouput of `java -version` and `javac -version`. But something, between `sdkman`, Gradle or IntelliJ is preventing the IDE from finding Java. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i set the jdk in intellij 9 on mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993601/how-can-i-set-the-jdk-in-intellij-9-on-mac)

Comment: Refer to the Intellij documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html?origin=old_help

Comment: Thanks @Jolta but **this is not a duplicate!!!** Unlike that other question and the helpdoc link you posted, I want **Gradle** to configure my IDEA project files for me. I have *absolutely* no interest whatsoever in manually configuring anything in the IDE. Gradle can and should be doing all of this for me. So again, its not an IntelliJ config question, it s a glitch between OSX, Gradle, IDEA and possibly sdkman. Please do not flag this as a dupe!

Comment: Not a dupe, how else can I say this?!?

Comment: It might be not a duplicate but is not a programming question either. Anyway, probably you have to set your JAVA_HOME environment variable, see [this blog](http://codepulsive.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x.html) 

Also, try opening a ticket with [IntelliJ support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731), they are very attentive and will follow up with you until you get the right answer.  

And finally don't forget to answer your own question when you find the solution. :)

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set, and if *any* questions about Gradle or IntelliJ are off-topic here, my name is Julius Caesar.

Comment: What does your name has to do with this? pfff Anyway, your attitude towards the people trying to help you is not the best. I've just did what you've described and it [works as expected](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yCZvX.png)

Comment: Ugghhh, the old "you attitude towards others falsely accusing your question as a dupe" defense, that moldy chestnut...

Comment: Uh? what are you talking about? sigh, anyway, I would really recommend you open a ticket with intellj support, they are really good at it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although i got it running by removing the .idea folder and reimporting the project by pointing to my build.gradle file. In the import dialog i selected the .ipr structure instead of using the idea "folder based structure" (default)

When executing `gradle idea` it will then generate an .ipr file in your project root configuring your project.
In my case the jdk was set properly and my modules were initialized correctly.

The reason behind using the .ipr files is, that the gradle idea plugin can't work with the directory based structure. See also:

- [directory based idea project with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253416/directory-based-idea-project-with-gradle)
- https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1041 (open for 6 years now)

Since i figured this out today i'm not sure how good this is working. Or what are the differences between directory based and .ipr based (.ipr based seems older?).